# FFmpeg - Streaming from a rtsp server to a rtmp server - loosing packages

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, rtsp, rtmp

I'm trying to stream a video from a rtsp server to a rtmp one using FFmpeg.
Tried multiple arguments for my command :

```
ffmpeg.exe -re -i "rtsp://10.65.28.251:11442/video/live" -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:v libx264 -tune animation -preset fast -crf 23 -maxrate 4M -bufsize 8M -f flv "rtmp://10.65.58.21:1935/rec/XB"

ffmpeg.exe -re -i "rtsp://10.65.28.251:11442/video/live" -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f flv "rtmp://10.65.52.131:1935/rec/XB
```

I'm loosing a lot of packages as seen in the picture. I'm pretty new to FFmpeg so I'm pretty sure I'm messing up the parameters somehow.

My goal is to get a video on rtmp with min 30fps and as least lost packages as possible. If needed a downsize of the video quality would be fine.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try without `-re` input option. IIRC, that option artificially slows down input stream as if its coming from a recording device. Also, if you can just copy streams that'll lower the computational needs.

Comment: Thanks! Removing -re made a big difference. I'll post below my full command

Answer (score 3):

As [kesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4516027/kesh) pointed above removing -re made a big difference. I ended up with this command which holds pretty good quality at 30fps.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "rtsp://serversource:11442" -filter:v fps=fps=30 -crf 40 -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -f flv "rtmp://servertarget:1935"
```